# My for-loop gets stuck, but doesn't exit out of loop. It reaches a certain number and just stops my whole program

Tags: java, for-loop

Here is the code. It gets stuck in the for-loop and only executes 4 times [0,3].
The input for it is:
6 5
1 2
1 3
1 4
1 5
5 6

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class MedianNode{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int nodes = in.nextInt();
        int edges = in.nextInt();
        ArrayList<Integer>[] graph = new ArrayList[nodes];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++){
            graph[i] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        }
        int a;
        int b;
        //graph[in.nextInt()].add(in.nextInt());

        
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes; i++){
            a = in.nextInt()-1;
            b = in.nextInt()-1;
            graph[a].add(b);
            graph[b].add(a);
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(graph));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running your code with the input that you gave, the loop does not get stuck, but the program crashes due to an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` caused by your last input (the `6`). You initialize your `graph` array with 6 nodes, essentially giving it valid indices 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5. With your last input being 6, you attempt to access `graph[6]`, which does not exist and crashes your program. Depending on what your goal is here, you could either fix the input, fix the algorithm or catch these cases and give a custom error message.

Comment: You should try executing it yourself, making sure that you are watching the console. Note that when you are working with 6 nodes, your code requires 2 + 2*6 inputs before it'll terminate. Your example only contains 12 inputs, so your code will be waiting for another 2 inputs in that instance.